# How to repair an interrupted Game Bar (MP4) recoding?

Tags: windows-10, screen-recorder

I recorded my screen using the Game Bar recording feature.

The recording was interrupted when the battery power ran out on my laptop. After recharging I was able to locate the recording in the usual folder.

It has a large size but does not show a video length. I am not able to open the video file (mp4). Any ideas how to fix this file?

Comment: Sorry to hear about this. I would recommend installing FFmpeg on your machine and running a command such as this one: `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy output.mp4`. What usually happens in cases like this is the MP4 *container* is damaged and by copying the contents of the MP4 into a new MP4 file (container) it will be playable again.

Answer (score 0):

`FFmpeg` is a good tool to use for this. It is used for various forms of video processing and editing, but can also repair corrupted files (like your screen recording) with the simplest of commands.

Here is a [download link](https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/packages/ffmpeg-5.0.1-essentials_build.zip) to it. Unzip that file, and then you can use `ffmpeg.exe` to fix your video, by running the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i screen_recording_broken.mp4 -c copy screen_recording_fixed.mp4
```

Replacing the name of each `screen_recording_broken` with the corrupted video file.

After that, you should be able to successfully play the video as `screen_recording_fixed.mp4`!